# How can I make a certain column(that's not an Id) a foreign key when both tables are already populated with data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I know my question might not be clear so I'm going to explain my case here briefly.

I have 2 tables: Cities, and CitiesDatas.

[CitiesTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afwpF.png)
[CitiesDatasTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t95Oi.png)

My problem is that I'm trying to make the column Name of table CitiesDatas a foreign key since their value is the same as the column City from table Cities and therefore connect the 2 tables.

I know adding the CityId would be better but I have a lot of data and I don't want to type each Id for each City manually.(maybe if I could add a where clause in the query when adding the foreign key I could do that, the where clause would look like this where CitiesDatas.Name equals Cities.City)

Also, not every City has a column in CitiesDatas, but every column in CitiesDatas belongs to a City in Cities.

Keep in mind, I'm not the most experienced person with databases, so be kind to me :)

P.s The reason the tables look like this is because they were converted from 2 json files.

Comment: You can add CityId column without doing it manually, search for update from select statement in SQL Server.

Comment: 'the column City from table Cities' does not exist - there is a name column.., you don't need a foreign key to connect tables, if you do have a key it's for referential integrity and you may have a problem creating a FK if the datatypes differ, You should be storing city id in cities data you can achive this with an alter table to add the column and an update to add the value

Comment: Please post table definitions as text rather than links.

Comment: Thank you @Dordi for the comment, that looks like it will help me a ton. I'm gonna check now or tomorrow and see if that fixed my issue.

Comment: I know I don't need a foreign key to connect tables. Initially we did this to replace the foreign key:
var result = from c in _context.Cities
join data in _context.CitiesDatas on c.City equals data.Name
where c.City == city
select new
{
c.City,
c.Canton,
data.CantonCode,
c.District,
c.Population,
c.ProportionOfForeigners,
c.AverageAgeOrYears,
c.Area,
data.HeaderTitle,
data.HeaderContent,
data.List1,
data.List2,
data.CityBodyTitle,
data.CityBodyContent,
data.CityBodyTitle2,
data.CityBodyContent2,
data.SpokenLanguage
};

Comment: But I don't like doing this because then if we ever add other fields to the table I'd have to update each query. @P.Salmon